# Find all possible values of $c^2$ in a system of equations.

Tags: numerical-methods, contest-math, systems-of-equations

Numbers $x,y,z,c\in \Bbb R$ satisfy the following system of equations:
$$x(y+z)=20$$
$$y(z+x)=13$$
$$z(x+y)=c^2$$
Find all possible values of $c^2$.

To try to solve this, I expanded the equations:
$$xy+xz=20$$
$$yz+xy=13$$
$$xz+yz=c^2$$
Then I subtracted the first equation from the second one to get:
$$xz-yz=7$$
I added and subtracted this equation with the 3rd and got the following equations:
$$2yz=7-c^2$$
$$2xz=7+c^2$$
I then added these equations, factored out $2z$ and divided by $2$ to get:
$$z(x+y)=7$$
So, I found one possible value of $c^2 = 7$. How do I find the other values if they exist or how do I prove that there are no other values if they don't? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On simplifying you will get

$yz=\frac{c^{2}-7}{2}$

$xz=\frac{c^{2}+7}{2}$

$xy=\frac{33-c^{2}}{2}$

Multiply above equations to get:

$x^{2}y^{2}z^{2}=\frac{c^{2}-7}{2}\frac{c^{2}+7}{2}\frac{33-c^{2}}{2}$

Since $x^{2}y^{2}z^{2} \geq 0$, therefore $7\leq c^2 \leq 33$. However, when you substitute it back to get $x,\ y,\ \& \ z$, you will find that $c^{2} \neq 7,\ 33$. Thus, possible value of $c^2$ are

$7 < c^2 < 33$

Answer (score 0):

You just proved that it is necessary that $c^2 = 7$ if $z \neq 0$ (because you divided by $2z$). Now, you have to find a solution to the system (where $z\neq 0$) with $c^2 = 7$. If there is no such solution, there is no $c$ in this case. Also, consider the system with $z = 0$.

EDIT: I relied on what you wrote. When you subtract you do not have $2yz = 7-c^2$, but $2yz = c^2-7$. Sorry for the confusion. And yes, $c^2 = 7$ is not possible.

Comment: A system with z = 0 is impossible, because we get that $xy = 20$ and $xy = 13$, that's a contradiction. Right?

Comment: No, $c^2 = 7$ is not necessary.  For example, with$c=4$ there is a solution $x = \sqrt{782}/6, y = 3 \sqrt{782}/46, z = 3 \sqrt{782}/34$.

Comment: Indeed. I edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c^2 = s$.  Eliminating $x$ and $y$, you get an equation in $s$ and $z$:
$$ s^2 + 2 z^2 s - 66 z^2 - 49 $$
Thus 
$$ z^2 = \dfrac{s^2 - 49}{66 - 2 s}$$
Since $z^2 \ge 0$, we need either $s \le -7$ or $7 \le s < 33$.  This corresponds to $\sqrt{7} \le c < \sqrt{33}$.   We then have
$$ \eqalign{y &= \dfrac{z (33 - c^2)}{c^2 + 7}\cr
x &= \dfrac{z(33 - c^2)}{c^2-7} \cr}$$
In particular, $c = \sqrt{7}$ is not possible.  So the result is that
$\sqrt{7} < c < \sqrt{33}$.